# How to keep the while loop in a function when reading data with multiple conditions?

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

This code is giving me exceptional data because I used `!pinFound`. *So I want it to get the details to be in a condition*. It means, if I want the `pinFound` result then it should only give me the `pinFound` result or if I want `!pinFound` result then it should only give me the `!pinFound` result.

*I don't want both results to be printed at the same time* **Plus I have multiple functions to read data from. So I don't want to repeat while(fgets(...)) in the main function again and again.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int i;
char line[STRING_LEN], *lineOne = NULL, *numbers[5], pinFind[STRING_LEN], *pinFound = NULL;  
int find(FILE * fname, char *findPin){
    while(fgets(line, STRING_LEN, fname)){  
        lineOne = strtok(line, "\n");
        numbers[0] = strtok(lineOne, ",");
        for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            numbers[i] = strtok(NULL, ",");
        pinFound = strstr(numbers[2], findPin);
        if(!pinFound)
            return line;    
    }
}

int main(){
    FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    printf("Enter the pin code: ");
    scanf("%s", pinFind);

    find(fp1, pinFind);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("%s\n", numbers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This code is giving me exceptional data because I used `!pinFound`" - this is rather unclear. What exceptional data? Why did you use `!pinFound`? What output did you expect, for what exact input?

Comment: Btw, making all these variables global is a bad idea, but making `i` a global variable is particularly dangerous.

Comment: @Groo **exceptional data** means the data in which entered pin code is not found.

Comment: @Groo I have been working to solve this problem for so long, and i am new in C

Comment: Your logic seems the opposite of what is should be. Shouldn't you return is the "pin" ***is*** found? As in `if (pinFound)`? Then remember to return something once the `while` loop ends as well.

Comment: Also, `return line` (where `line` is a string) in a function declared to return `int`? What is the function really supposed to return? And what will the `main` function do with the value that is returned?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah bro you're right. But I want to get the details to be in a condition. It means, if I want the pinFound result then it should only give me the pinFound result or if I want !pinFound result then it should only give me the !pinFound result.

Comment: If the `while` loop ends, then you know that the "pin" haven't been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you would like to extract the file iteration logic from the rest of the processing.

Basic change that would allow you to get this would be simply:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

// parse next line, return true if line was parsed
bool nextLine(FILE * fname, char *findPin)
{
    if (fgets(line, STRING_LEN, fname))
    {
        lineOne = strtok(line, "\n");
        numbers[0] = strtok(lineOne, ",");
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            numbers[i] = strtok(NULL, ",");
        pinFound = strstr(numbers[2], findPin);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then in main:

```
FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");

printf("Enter the pin code: ");
scanf("%s", pinFind);

while (nextLine(fp1, pinFind))
{
    // if you are here, line was parsed, so
    // check the value of 'pinFound'

    if (pinFound)
        doSomething(numbers);
    else
        doSomethingElse(numbers);
}

fclose(fp1);
```

For a homework project, this should more or less do the trick, but I would recommend encapsulating the state between `nextLine` calls in a separate struct, instead of keeping it global. Making all these variables global is a bad idea, but making `i` a global variable is a **particularly dangerous bad idea**.

Comment: thank you! another question is that why `i` is dangerous?

Comment: If you are constantly changing global state all over the code, every seemingly simple function call like can potentially change the outcome of any subsequent function call. This makes it very hard to ensure program correctness once it grows a bit, as the result of a function will not be determined solely by its parameters (pure function). If `i` is global, then seemingly innocent code like `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { doSomething(); }` allows the `doSomething` function to change `i` inside the loop and break things. If you just scope it (`for (int i = 0; ...)`), you save yourself the trouble.